# Consolidation of Same rows by adding a Column Value in R Data Frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame that I have constructed in R. What I am trying to do is add the values for Column Total, removing the duplicated rows, retaining each column. So for the LGA = albury, offence type = assault, month = Jan and year = 1995, the total = 7 + 29 + 12 (48).

[Dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1C2b5.png)

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). Images are not the right way to share data/code.

Answer (score 1):

Using base R you could do:

```
aggregate(Total~., df, sum)
```

Comment: Thanks! After performing this, how would I next remove the month column, and then sum the amounts based on the year?